# Show that a polynomial is solvable (soluble)

Tags: galois-theory, solvable-groups

So I've recently encounter the problem:

> Show that the Galois group of $x^{10}-2$ over Q is solvable

I've been trying tp show that the splitting field of this pol is contained in a radical extension but it didn't turn out right.

Is there anyway to approach this type of problem?

Comment: For the lolz you can factor it $(x^5+\sqrt{2})(x^5-\sqrt{2})$. Those two factors can be divided by $x\pm2^{1/10}$, respectively, giving polynomials of degree $4$. Then those can be solved in radicals.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta_{10}) \subseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta_{10}, 2^{1/10})$.

The first extension is cyclotomic hence abelian.

The second extension is cyclic.

Comment: therefore the splitting field is cyclic and hence a radical extension. am I right?

Comment: The splitting field is a radical extension of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{10})$, which is an abelian extension of $\Bbb Q$, so the whole extension is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of this polynomial equation are expressible as $x=\root 10\of 2$,  hence, by definition, as it is expressed as a radical in the coefficients, it is solvable by radicals.

Comment: That is not the only root of the polynomial.

Comment: @cardinalred In quadratic case we can simply write $(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac} )/(2a)$ where the square root sign can represent either  of the two square roots. Same way here it can represent any of the 10 of the tenth roots.

Comment: Yes. I just have one more question. Am I understood this wrongly: Q($\zeta_{10}$) is abelian extension, extended by root 10 of 2, then it is a cyclic extension.